# Tikz Change one coordinate only

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw a line from a point on a circle, and I want that line to be horizontal and stopping at a given x. However I don't know what the y value is, since im deriving that from the circle.

```
\draw (-5, 0) circle (1cm);
\draw (-5, 0) ++(45:1cm) -- (-3.5, 0.705);
```

leads to a slightly off line, since 0.705 is my best guess. Whats the right way to solve that?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we can test as it is. brw, for second line of your code fragment tra: `\draw (-5, 0) ++(45:1cm) -- ++(1.5, 0);` if this gives what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-|` coordinate specification:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \draw (-5, 0) circle (1cm);
    \draw (-5, 0) ++(45:1cm) coordinate(a) -- (a -| 1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am marking the starting point as coordinate `a`, and then drawing a line to a point going horizontally from `a` and at the vertical of `(1,0)` --- so the final point will have the `y`  coordinate of `a` and the `x` coordinate `1`.

[image]